# c# - unreachable code detected, break inside if statement inside for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, break

```
bool AllQuestionsAnswered()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(count); i++)
        {
            string _1 = "rbchoice1_" + i;
            string _2 = "rbchoice2_" + i;
            string _3 = "rbchoice3_" + i;
            string _4 = "rbchoice4_" + i;

            bool c1 = ((RadioButton)tabControl1.Controls[_1]).Checked;
            bool c2 = ((RadioButton)tabControl1.Controls[_2]).Checked;
            bool c3 = ((RadioButton)tabControl1.Controls[_3]).Checked;
            bool c4 = ((RadioButton)tabControl1.Controls[_4]).Checked;

            if (c1 == false && c2 == false && c3 == false && c4 == false)
            {
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

My code above gives me a warning "Unreachable code detected". How can I fix it? Will it be okay if I just ignore the warning? Please help.

Comment: Simply remove the `break;` statement.

Comment: You should learn a few things from this: 1) Learn to actually understand the code you're writing, instead of just pushing keys on the keyboard; 2) Learn to use the debugger, which would tell you **exactly** why that line can't be reached; and 3) Learn to read the code, and you'll figure out why your loop is totally unnecessary (watch the values you're assigning to the `string _` variables when you step through the code in the debugger).

Comment: Why do you think the loop is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

if `return false;` have reached then `AllQuestionsAnswered()` will go out then there will be no need fo the `break;` statement; remove `break;` and you will be good to go !

Answer (score 0):

You have to note two things here. The break can be used inside a loop to Stops its iteration and execute next statement in the block that comes after the loop. Whereas the return will kick you out from the enclosing method, So the code after return will never be executed. Here you need not to use `break` since return will do that job for you. And if you remove `return false;` and continue with break then this method will always returns `true`

Answer (score -1):

As Rob said in the comment:
You have a line that returns and following that a line that breaks.
The break is unreachable (you just returned).